# Occasionally getting YouTube iframe player error message "An error occurred. Please try again later"

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

I developed an app with YouTube IFrame player and it has worked normally for years. However, some users recently reported they consistently get an error message where they are unable to play YouTube videos anymore.
As you can see, the picture shown below simply says that "An error occurred. Please try again later. (Playback ID: qZvv8JiWqbS1J5oI)".

[image: YouTube IFrame player error message]

I have received this sort of feedback from users since two days ago.

The following codes are snippets for initializing a YouTube IFrame player.

Load IFrame API:

```js
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
```

Initialize a YouTube player:

```js
const ytPlayer = new YT.Player(YT_PLAYER_DIV_ID, {
  width: PLAYER_WIDTH,
  playerVars: {
    playsinline: 1,
    controls: 0,
    showinfo: 0,
    rel: 0,
    start: 0,
    iv_load_policy: 3,
    modestbranding: 1
  },
  events: {
    'onReady': onPlayerReady,
    'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange,
    'onError': onPlayerError
  }
});
```

I noticed the callback function `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady` is always being called while none of `onPlayerReady` and `onPlayerError` are triggered, that means the IFrame API should be successfully loaded.

Is there any possible reason that caused this issue?

Comment: It happened to me when I was testing the YouTube Iframe API with different settings; I think YT does that as a way to block multiple petitions to its app made from the same IP / PC. For discard any local errors, check the console of your browser when you get those errors and [edit] your question with those details.

Comment: Hi @MarcoAurelioFernandezReyes, thank you for your information! Unfortunately, this issue is not reproducible on my side, so I cannot check errors from the console. But we found that reinstalling app may resolve the issue (not sure if it works for all users so far).